# Axios catch not working with Laravel API but only for errors

Tags: laravel, axios

I have a React app set up to call a Laravel API using Santum but I'm having trouble with API calls that return error codes. Succesful results work fine however.

For example, if I run:

```
axios.get('http://website.test/api/collections')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Then I get back a list of collections as expected and all is good.

However, if I try on something that should error (like a 404):

```
axios.get('http://website.test/api/doesnotexist')
.then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
})
.catch(function (error) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

It always calls the 'then' function rather than the catch but the contents is:

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)
```

A very similar thing happens for validation errors with a 422 response.

I have set up Sanctum as per the docs and axios uses `withCredentials`. As I said, 200/201 responses from the API work fine but I just can't figure out why errors do not? There are no CORS errors showing in console either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the answer is my own stupidity.

I had an axios interceptor in another file that I copied in from another project without checking and it was marking all errors other than 401 as being OK.

Not sure what the etiquette is here but if this should be deleted then fine, otherwise I'm happy to leave it in case it helps anyone else who is careless as I.